# why is it that when we differentiate a logarithmic function with a number in front we keep the number in front?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

let's say i have to differentiate
$y = ln3x $
i know that this will be
$ dy/dx = 3/3x $
but let's say i have to differentiate
$ y = 2ln3x $
why does $dy/dx$ then equate :
$ (2 * 3)/3x  = 6/3x$  ?
i want to know how come we don't do anything to the coefficient 2 in this case. how come it just stays the same?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} (2f(x)) = 2\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. Have you seen something like that rule before?

Comment: @DavidK nope. what is it called? i have heard ''apply linearity'' in integration but not in differentiation on this site : https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: Differentiation is also linear: i.e. for $D=\frac{d}{dx}$, we have
$D(f(x)+g(x)) = D(f(x)) + D(g(x))$
and
$D(c\cdot f(x)) = c\cdot D(f(x))$.
This is exactly what it means to be linear.

Comment: could you elaborate on the term ''linear'' ? thanks.

Comment: What about taking derivatives of polynomials? Are you comfortable with $\frac{d}{dx} (3x^5) = 15 x^4$, for example? If so, then you are already using this rule. It has nothing to do with functions being logarithmic or not.

Comment: yes.im familiar with taking the derivative of polynomials.

Comment: so you mean to tell me that we only differentiate the function and that the coefficient is not part of the function? but wait, the coefficient is part of the function. it forms the function...

Comment: Certainly if $g(x) = 3x^5$ then the coefficient $3$ **is** part of the function $g(x)$. But that means $g(x)$ is always exactly $3$ times as large as the function $f(x) = x^5,$ and it can be shown that $g(x)$ therefore grows exactly $3$ times as fast as $f(x).$ So to get the derivative of $g(x)$ you can first find the derivative of $f(x)$ and then multiply by $3.$ You would have had to do something like this to differentiate a general polynomial, although perhaps nobody said it was a general rule for all differentiable functions.

Comment: how can it be shown that g(x) grows 3 times as fast as f(x)?

Answer (score 2):

One good way to see it is through the product rule. Recall that, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differentiable functions,

$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\cdot g(x)) = f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(g(x))+g(x)\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) $

We can view a constant as a function! $c(x) = c$ for all $x$. Furthermore, we know that $\frac{d}{dx}c = 0$. Inserting this into the product rule, we see that

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}(c\cdot f(x)) =& \: c\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))+f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(c) \\
=& \: c\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) \: .
\end{align*}

If this was not familiar and did not make sense, then just take it as a rule: When differentiating a function times a constant, the result is the differentiated function times the constant.

Comment: '' c(x)=c for all x.'' please explain this part. i am not understanding.

Comment: how is a constant a function ? there is no variable in a constant.

Comment: A function can be thought of as a machine which, given an input, produces an output. A constant can be thought of as the function which, given ANY input, always gives the same output: the constant. Take for example the zero function, $y = 0$. For any $x$, this function is always zero - but it can still be thought of as a function of $x$.

Comment: so you mean to tell me that the function y=0 could be thought of as y=0x^0?

Comment: Exactly so. Brilliant way to think about it.